# Need help in putting flutter data to firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I've got bunch of model data on my flutter source code, which I want to add to firebase. The data is a normal list view data that contains listings of various houses, hotels, accommodation and stuff like that. Still new to the whole Flutter Firebase thing, so still learning/adapting a lot of stuff. I know this is not a user editable data so it doesnt has to be in realtime database. But there is no proper or definitive guide to follow.

Example of one these data models.

```
class HotelListData {
String imagePath;
String titleTxt;
String subTxt;
double dist;
double rating;
int reviews;
String perNight;
bool isfavorited;
List<String> features;
String desc;
String size;

  HotelListData({
    this.imagePath = '',
    this.titleTxt = '',
    this.subTxt = "",
    this.dist = 1.8,
    this.reviews = 80,
    this.rating = 4.5,
    this.perNight = '',
    this.size = '',
    this.isfavorited = false,
    this.features = const [
      "Flexible Payment",
      "Pet Allowed",
      "Unlimited Electricity"
    ],
    this.desc =
        "This is an issue on which the university is highly sensitive. The warm friendship you will lorem ipsum ipsum lorem",
  });

  static List<HotelListData> hotelList = <HotelListData>[
    HotelListData(
        imagePath: 'assets/images/kau7.jpg',
        titleTxt: 'Kau Building',
        subTxt: 'Granada, North Qaurter',
        dist: 0.0,
        reviews: 80,
        rating: 4.4,
        perNight: '\$1600',
        size: '1000',
        desc: 'Testing test'),
    HotelListData(
        imagePath: 'assets/images/ursala.jpg',
        titleTxt: 'Uursal Emporium',
        subTxt: 'England, Yorkshire',
        dist: 0.0,
        reviews: 74,
        rating: 4.5,
        perNight: '\$1800',
        desc: 'Testing test'),
    HotelListData(
        imagePath: 'assets/images/test.jpg',
        titleTxt: 'ALorem Ispisum',
        subTxt: 'Lorem land of ipsumsum',
        dist: 0.0,
        reviews: 62,
        rating: 4.0,
        perNight: '\$1900',
        desc: 'Testing test'),
```

The problem is, I've seen a bunch of tutorials and articles and all of that shows the data going the other way around, its all from firebase to the app, or from app to the firebase storage. But nothing from the code to directly to firebase storage. Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: There is plenty of documentation for uploading files to Firebase Storage.  https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage#uploading-files

Comment: Don't repost the same question multiple times please. Especially not when your previous question was closed. You can address the reason why your question was closed by clicking the edit link under your previous question. By addressing the feedback your question then becomes eligible for reopening.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks, just needed to learn this.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Alright, I'll follow the proper process now.